# Where to buy Rabbi Ouri Cherki's books?

Tags: jewish-books

Does anyone know where I could find Rabbi Ouri (Oury) Cherkie's books to purchase? In particular, I'm trying to locate his commentary on the Kuzari for a friend's upcoming birthday and all the websites I've found were not helpful. This sefer is in Hebrew.

Comment: Do you live in Israel?

Comment: Nope - hopefully one day soon!

Comment: You can join the Ourim WhatsApp group here and contact the group managers directly: https://chat.whatsapp.com/H2izUidR6vFHUXbuxmIRmI

Comment: Yes, thank you. I was able to get in contact with the Ourim folks, who have been really helpful. I got the inside scoop that they are translating Rav Cherki's books into French and English with the first to come out in a couple months from now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is never easy to know if a particular online store has them in stock, but here are a number of stores who claim to sell it. Did you try them all already?

- [Zolsefer](http://www.zolsefer.co.il/%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%91%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8-%D7%94%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%96%D7%A8%D7%99-%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%91-%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%A7%D7%99.html)
- [Hamadaf](https://www.hamadaf-y.co.il/%D7%97%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA/%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%94-%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A8/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8-%D7%94%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%96%D7%A8%D7%99-%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94%D7%9C/%D7%94%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%96%D7%A8%D7%99-%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%A7-%D7%90-%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%91-%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%A7%D7%99/)
- [Moshe Books](https://www.moshebooks.com/items/417425-%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%91%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8-%D7%94%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%96%D7%A8%D7%99-%D7%91)
- [Dshir](https://www.dshir.co.il/cat/28)
- [Ourim](https://ourim.org/product/%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%96%D7%A8%D7%99-%D7%91/)
- [Yefe](https://www.yefetks.co.il/p/%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%91%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8-%D7%94%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%96%D7%A8%D7%99-%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%A7-%D7%90---%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%91-%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99-%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%A7%D7%99)

Alternatively you could write to the manager of R Cherki's site ([here](http://ravsherki.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=3714:2013-01-21-22-34-28&catid=318:uncategorised&Itemid=101077)) and see if he knows of stores having it in stock.

Comment: Oh wow thank you. I did look at a few of those sites, but not all of them. If not, I'll reach out the site manager. Thank you very much!